# Calculation of descriptive statistics by group

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, grouping

I have a dataset that have collected from 2 different universities. Each one  includes students’ information like country, grades, age etc. I want to extract min, mean, max, standard deviation of grade and age by each country (they are grouped by their country) in each university and create table.

The code that I am using is following. I am repeating the code for min, max, and standard deviation for each university. Repeating the process is ok but when I create a table I want I need to go back to excel to combine statistics I obtained from this code. So is there any straight forward method to do this in R?

```
 stats_gr <- data %>%
 select(Country, Grades, Age) %>%
 group_by(country) %>%
 summarise(Grades = mean(Grades), Age=mean(Age))
```

[I want a table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07EDq.png)

Comment: not sure if this is what you whant, but you could write: summarise(Grades_mean = mean(Grades), Grades_in = min(Grades), Grades_max = max(Grades), Grades_sd = sd(Grades), Age_mean = mean(Age)...... . Or, as an alternative you could use do() instead of summarise and call psych::describe or any other premade descriptives function

Comment: Can you dput() the the dataframe after the select? (even just `dput(head(data))` would help)

Comment: What I want is to extract this table in R. I don't want to use excel to compile statistics  in a single table.

Comment: @EmilyKothe. I guess "data" is my original data.what variable should I replace "head" in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using knitr's kable() function.

## A fake dataset I generated just to fill the table. It's a single dataset that includes data from both universities for each country.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble::tribble(
           ~University, ~Countries, ~Grades, ~Age,
        "University-1",      "USA",      46,    29,
        "University-1",       "UK",      84,    30,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",       5,    28,
        "University-1",    "Spain",      40,    26,
        "University-1", "Portugal",      49,    29,
        "University-1",    "Italy",      16,    24,
        "University-1",      "USA",      34,    19,
        "University-1",       "UK",      66,    28,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",       9,    25,
        "University-1",    "Spain",      80,    20,
        "University-1", "Portugal",      55,    20,
        "University-1",    "Italy",       4,    21,
        "University-1",      "USA",      93,    18,
        "University-1",       "UK",      62,    28,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",      80,    30,
        "University-2",    "Spain",       1,    22,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      56,    25,
        "University-2",    "Italy",       9,    29,
        "University-2",      "USA",      40,    21,
        "University-2",       "UK",      54,    20,
        "University-2",   "Sweden",      60,    24,
        "University-2",    "Spain",      77,    21,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      22,    18,
        "University-2",    "Italy",      53,    29,
        "University-2",      "USA",      11,    21,
        "University-2",       "UK",      65,    27,
        "University-2",   "Sweden",      24,    27,
        "University-2",    "Spain",      18,    23,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      73,    19,
        "University-2",    "Italy",      79,    22,
        "University-1",      "USA",       2,    26,
        "University-1",       "UK",      83,    23,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",       5,    19,
        "University-1",    "Spain",      75,    19,
        "University-1", "Portugal",      12,    21,
        "University-1",    "Italy",      68,    29,
        "University-1",      "USA",     100,    21,
        "University-1",       "UK",      49,    21,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",      81,    20,
        "University-1",    "Spain",      99,    23,
        "University-1", "Portugal",      82,    24,
        "University-1",    "Italy",      23,    26,
        "University-1",      "USA",      86,    30,
        "University-1",       "UK",      50,    20,
        "University-1",   "Sweden",       4,    19,
        "University-2",    "Spain",      12,    25,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      12,    21,
        "University-2",    "Italy",      45,    21,
        "University-2",      "USA",      16,    26,
        "University-2",       "UK",      56,    23,
        "University-2",   "Sweden",      63,    24,
        "University-2",    "Spain",      37,    28,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      86,    21,
        "University-2",    "Italy",      95,    18,
        "University-2",      "USA",      56,    20,
        "University-2",       "UK",      27,    20,
        "University-2",   "Sweden",       3,    27,
        "University-2",    "Spain",      18,    27,
        "University-2", "Portugal",      68,    27,
        "University-2",    "Italy",      48,    21
        )
```

### Generate the table you want using dplyr and kable

```
  df %>% 
  group_by(University,Countries) %>%
  summarise(Grades_min = min(Grades), 
            Grades_mean = mean(Grades),
            Grades_max = max(Grades),
            Grades_sd = sd(Grades),
            Age_min = min(Age),
            Age_mean= mean(Age),
            Age_max = max(Age),
            Age_sd = sd(Age)) %>% 
  knitr::kable(col.names = c("University", 
                             "Country", 
                             "Min Grade", 
                             "Mean Grade", 
                             "Max Grade", 
                             "Grade SD", 
                             "Min Age", 
                             "Mean Age", 
                             "Max Age", 
                             "Age SD"))


|University   |Country  | Min Grade| Mean Grade| Max Grade| Grade SD| Min Age| Mean Age| Max Age|   Age SD|
|:------------|:--------|---------:|----------:|---------:|--------:|-------:|--------:|-------:|--------:|
|University-1 |Italy    |         4|   27.75000|        68| 27.95681|      21| 25.00000|      29| 3.366502|
|University-1 |Portugal |        12|   49.50000|        82| 28.82707|      20| 23.50000|      29| 4.041452|
|University-1 |Spain    |        40|   73.50000|        99| 24.61030|      19| 22.00000|      26| 3.162278|
|University-1 |Sweden   |         4|   30.66667|        81| 38.64022|      19| 23.50000|      30| 4.847680|
|University-1 |UK       |        49|   65.66667|        84| 15.31883|      20| 25.00000|      30| 4.195235|
|University-1 |USA      |         2|   60.16667|       100| 38.98931|      18| 23.83333|      30| 5.192944|
|University-2 |Italy    |         9|   54.83333|        95| 29.81554|      18| 23.33333|      29| 4.589844|
|University-2 |Portugal |        12|   52.83333|        86| 29.54601|      18| 21.83333|      27| 3.488075|
|University-2 |Spain    |         1|   27.16667|        77| 27.06597|      21| 24.33333|      28| 2.804758|
|University-2 |Sweden   |         3|   37.50000|        63| 29.03446|      24| 25.50000|      27| 1.732051|
|University-2 |UK       |        27|   50.50000|        65| 16.38088|      20| 22.50000|      27| 3.316625|
|University-2 |USA      |        11|   30.75000|        56| 21.06142|      20| 22.00000|      26| 2.708013|
```

The nice thing about this method is that it will work well if you want to use rmarkdown to knit to word. If you do that the table will look like this[image: screenshot of the generated table once knitted to word].

You can control the number of digits, table captions, or column alignment using the relevant kable arguments.

Comment: It worked very well. Thank you so much! Sorry just one more thing. What code should I add to the script If I want to bring "Grade" & "Age" at the top of min,mean,max, sd of them?

Comment: The kableExtra package will do this to export to HTML but I'm not sure if it will work to export to word.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `stargazer` suits you:

```
library(stargazer)
stats_gr <- data %>%
 select(Country, Grades, Age) %>%
 group_by(country) %>% stargazer(type="text")
```

Comment: It shows me this line "Statistic N Mean St. Dev. Min Pctl(25) Pctl(75) Max".